# How to model a box with a key using DDD?

Tags: domain-driven-design

User can create a box with text inside.
When a box is created it will have a key (UUID) assigned.
This key is then will be sent to recipient.
When recipient activates the key, he receives a text inside corresponding box to email.

So given this requirements I found 2 aggregate roots:
`Box` and `Key`

Here is a box creation flow (without fails)

```
CreateBox -> BoxCreated
BoxCreated -> CreateKey // handled by process manager
KeyCreated -> NotifyRecipient // handled by process manager
```

And activation flow (without fails)

```
ActivateKey -> KeyActivated
KeyActivated -> OpenBox // handled by process manager
OpenBox -> BoxOpened
BoxOpened -> SendContentToRecipient // handled by process manager
```

I wonder if it's correct approach to model such a system?

Because in traditional data-centric architecture I would probably have just one entity `Box` with a property `key`. And to activate a key I would just `SELECT * FROM Box WHERE key = $key` mark it as activated and save it back.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  What properties does this box have?  Is it just a textbox?

Comment: Yes. Box contains text.

Comment: If it's just a UI element, then it doesn't need to be an entity.  What does this text box's UUID uniquely identify?  It sounds like it might be something like a communication session between two users.

Comment: It's backend entities. Do you know about DDD terminology?

Comment: Yes, I'm familiar with DDD terminology.  I'm just not sure why a UI element would be considered an entity.  Your UI element (the textbox) should merely exist to expose Entity data to a user.  It itself is not an Entity.

Comment: What UI are you talking about?

Comment: I would just have a Box AR with text and key value. The key itself doesn't need to be an AR. Activating the key could just be opening the box by providing the right key. `box.openWith(key)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to me the Box and Key are part of the same aggregate root.

Use Cases:

```
When a user requests a box be built
Then a box is created
 And a key fitting the box is created
 And a recipient key is created

Given a created box
  And a created matching key
  And a recipient notification with key
 When a recipient uses the key from the notification
 Then the box is opened (seal is broken? key is broken?)
  And the content of the box is delivered
```

In such a case, the aggregate root (consistency boundary) here is the locksmith? :) The box and keys for it are issued from the locksmith or box factory.

Command/Event workflow could be:

```
BuildBox (with contents) -> BoxCreated
                            KeyCreated (not sure if needed?)
                            RecipientKeyCreated

OpenBox (with Key) -> KeyConsumed (one-time use?)
                      BoxOpened
                      ContentsRemoved

DeliverKeyToRecipient -> (side effects like email)
                         KeyDeliveredToRecipient (if it's important to know)

// process manager
RecipientKeyCreated -> DeliverKeyToRecipient
```

You could try to deliver the key as part of the box building workflow, but often such concerns are external integrations or have other practical policies that you want to handle outside of the domain. Maybe they are even handled by a separate bounded context like Shipping.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! There is a problem with `OpenBox` command. To process a command I need `aggregateId`. However `boxId` is not known to recipient. So give `key` I can route it to `RecipientKey` aggregate or however you name it. What do you think?

Comment: Keys often have the number of the container they open, so just embed the aggregate id in the key. (In my case, aggregate ids are like `bc-aggregate-idnum` so embedding just idnum is good enough). Or keep a lookup table on the view side from key id to aggregate id so you can issue the appropriate command. [Article about lost keys](http://www.cleveland.com/consumeraffairs/index.ssf/2011/10/a_found_key_a_lost_safe_deposi.html)